# Cosmos Db: Container.DeleteItemAsync<T>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey) (UpsertItemAsync) has a large RequestCharge

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

For adding documents to the Cosmos Db I normally use the
`Container.UpsertItemAsync(doc, new PartitionKey(partitionKey))` method.
Replacing the document takes twice the request charge as inserting the document.

I have re-written the method to use:

```
Container.DeleteItemAsync<T>(doc.Id, partitionKey);
Container.CreateItemAsync<T>(doc, partitionKey);
```

The insert of my huge document costs: 626 RU
Updating the same document costs 626 RU for deleting and 626 RU for creating.

Switching it to

```
Container.ReplaceItemAsync(doc, doc.Id, partitionKey);
```

Costs 1250 RU's , which is in line with the Delete/Create action.

But why does a Delete (or Update) costs that much RU's and how can I reduce this.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it by limiting the amount of properties that are indexed. The work to keep your indexing policy up to date is reflected in the RU's that are used, which is why a delete seems to expensive. So if you have a lot of properties that don't need to be indexed because they are not used to filter or order results of queries can significantly reduce the RU's used.

You can also check if it's feasible to replace your `ReplaceItemAsync` with the `PatchItemAsync` method. Especially if you only need to update a few properties it can significantly reduce the RU's required to make a small update.

```cs
var patch = new List<PatchOperation>()
{
    PatchOperation.Add("/example", "It works :)!"),
};
var response = await container.PatchItemAsync<MyItem>(myId, myPk, patch);
```

Comment: Database has only in this test 3 documents, so indexing should not be a problem.
Indexing is done only on two extra  fields "/type/?", "/data/id/?"
Since the structure of the document is very complex, It's almost not duable to make a list of PatchOperations  (and btw. at this point I don't have the knowledge of what the document was before, so I need  to collect this.

Comment: The amount of documents doesn't matter. The index still needs to update the index tree with the same information. If you only have two properties indexed the document must be absolutely massive (~500kb in size?). In that case there's little you can do apart from making it smaller.

Comment: The document is even bigger...  ~ 1 Mb. Wich is actually quite normal for these kind of documents. I thought that the maximum size of a CosmosDb document was  2 Mb.

Comment: @Bart - 1MB is large, especially for searchable metadata. If you have an unbounded array (an array that can keep growing), this will eventually be a problem (your app will break if you exceed max doc size). Yes, 2MB is the limit,  but encoding etc eats up part of that 2MB.